# Переадресация сайта

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Нужен скрипт который бы делал переадресацию с сайта на другую страницу в определенное время.

Вот что получилось.

```
<?php
 $date = new DateTime('now');
         $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Athens'));
     if ($date->format('H')>=10 && $date->format('H')<=21  ){
        if ($date->format('H')==21 && $date->format('i')<45)    
          echo "<script>window.location = '/'</script>";                  
        else if($date->format('H')<21)
          echo "<script>window.location = '/'</script>";
     } 
?>
```

Comment: Перенесите код в тело вопроса, и обрисуйте, что конкретно у вас не получилось

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы сайт делал переадресацию на страницу после 21.45 до 10.00

Answer (score 1):

пробуй

```
if( $condition ){

   Header("Location: somewhere.php");

} else {

   Header("Location: <!-- m --><span class="postlink">http://www.google.com</span><!-- m -->");

}
```

или

```
if($condition)

   print "<script language="Javascript">document.location.href='page_a.php' ;</script>";

else

   print "<script language="Javascript">document.location.href='page_b.php' ;</script>";
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.

Comment: Лучше или убрать)) зачем принтовать js который сразу делает редирект?

Answer (score 1):

Вы пишете, что вам нужен редект с 21-45 до 10-00, а в коде у вас всё с дочностью до наоборот. Я упростил ваш код.

```
<?php

  $date = new DateTime('now');
  $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Athens'));

  //$hour = $date->format('H');
  $hour = 21;
  //$minute = $date->format('i');
  $minute = 40;

  if ($hour < 10) {
    echo "redirect #1";
  } elseif ($hour == 21 && $minute >= 45) {
    echo "redirect #2";
  } elseif ($hour > 21) {
    echo "redirect #3";
  } else {
    echo "no redirect";
  }
```

Мой код можно отладить. Чтобы проверить правильность выполнения - вместо $hour и $minute можно подставить контрольные значения "до", "внутри" и "после" нужного диапазона.